# Why is fitting a polynomial faster than changing polynomial basis?

Tags: performance, numpy, curve-fitting, polynomials

Given some data points on the interval [–1, 1] and the best-fit Chebyshev polynomial to those points, I want to convert the Chebyshev polynomial to a Legendre polynomial.

There are 2 ways to do it, as shown in the code below. The direct way is to call `convert(kind = Legendre)` on the Chebyshev polynomial, which took 19.591 seconds. The alternative is to call `Legendre.fit` on the data points, which took only 3.356 seconds.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Chebyshev, Legendre
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
y = 1.0 / (1 + x ** 2) + 1e-3 * np.random.random(1000)
T = Chebyshev.fit(x, y, 99)

from timeit import timeit
timeit("T.convert(kind = Legendre)", setup = "from __main__ import x, y, T, Legendre",
       number = 200)
timeit("Legendre.fit(x, y, 99)", setup = "from __main__ import x, y, Legendre",
       number = 200)
```

**Question**: Why is `Legendre.fit` much faster than `convert(kind = Legendre)`? Am I doing it wrongly?

Comment: Two remarks: 1) on my computer, the time difference is much less, 3.8 vs 2.7 seconds, but still in favor of the fit function. 2) the docs explicitely state that the convert function can result in buggy behavior sometimes, so that's another reason to avoid those ... 

More generally, the fit function is a least-squares fit that is probably a well-written optimized C call behind the hood, whereas convert might use slower python calls/loops. But this is not much more than a guess ..

Comment: The convert method is all python and, instead of evaluating the Chebyshev series at an array of numbers, evaluates the series for an Legendre series representing the polynomial `x` in the new basis. It is a very flexible method for converting between series, but it isn't fast. Especially when the series get large.